# Lowercase letters not having underlined

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, underline

I want to have in a link the lowercase letters not having underlined. This seems to be tricky. I tried to solve it with a "span" or do I have to do it another way?

```
.text a:link {
    color: #FFF;
    border-bottom: solid 2px;
}

.lowercase {
    border-bottom:none !important;
 }
```

The HTML is the following:

```
<a href="http://www.singbei.com" target="_blank">sin<span class="lowercase">g</span>bei</a>
```

Is it easier than I think?

Comment: [Like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/nyjdq482/)

Comment: You aren't assigning your `.text` class to anything by the way. That may fix your problem.

Comment: @Notulysses post it as answer ;)

Comment: All letters in your posted code *are* lowercase.

Comment: Bottom border is not the same as underlining. Perhaps better, but not the same thing at all. And the code posted shows no effort in preventing the default underlining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, you can fake the borders:

```css
.text {background-color: #000; padding: 15px;}

.text a:link {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: solid 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.text a:link .lowercase {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

#### Preview

[image]

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/qjw1Lc3z/

Comment: Thank You! Works Perfect - and easy... @Hashem, you are right, all my letters are lowercase... Stupid me.

Answer (score 2):

*First solution, using `:not()` selector :*

```
a > span:not(.lowercase ) { border-bottom: solid 2px; }
a { text-decoration:none; }
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nyjdq482/)

*Second solution :*

```
a span { border-bottom: solid 2px; }
a span.lowercase { border:none;}
a { text-decoration:none; }
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nyjdq482/1/)

(*Maybe*) You can also find useful  `text-transform` CSS property which you can see in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nyjdq482/2/).

Answer (score 0):

how about,

```
.lowercase{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```